# huge performance difference between two PostgreSQL 8.4 releases on FreeBSD 8.2 virtual machines

Tags: django, performance, postgresql

I have a question about PostgreSQL performance differences.

I am developing a django web application on a MAC OS X system and the web application has to be deployed on a FreeBSD server. On a page of the system there is a ajax controlled data entry field. In this field you can enter a city name and when you enter two characters or more the system starts to look for the cities in the database and presents a drop-down of cities conforming these 2 (or more) characters at the beginning of the string.

All this seems to work well until I deployed it on FreeBSD servers. The first deployment was alright but the second deployment shows a huge performance difference.

This is a list of test results:

```
system1 proc: Intel Core 2 Duo 3.06 GHz, mem: 8GB. :
OS: OS X 10.6.8, 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; 
root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386
DB: PostgreSQL 8.4.5 on i386-apple-darwin10.5.0, compiled by GCC i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664), 64-bit

Tests system1:
query   parameter       time in ms
01      'de%'           909
02      'de%'           886
03      'den%'          132
04      'den %'         115
05      'den h%'        115
06      'den ha%'       117
07      'den haa%'      95
08      'den haag%'     100

host: system1
guest: parallels virtual machine, proc: 2 cpu, mem: 1 GB.
system2 
OS: 8.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE #0: Thu Feb 17 02:41:51 UTC 2011     root@mason.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
DB: PostgreSQL 8.4.7 on amd64-portbld-freebsd8.2, compiled by GCC cc (GCC) 4.2.1 20070719  [FreeBSD], 64-bit

Tests system2:
query   parameter       time in ms
01      'de%'           1178
02      'de%'           857
03      'den%'          298
04      'den %'         233
05      'den h%'        134
06      'den ha%'       132
07      'den haa%'      132
08      'den haag%'     136

host: system1
guest: parallels virtual machine, proc: 2 cpu, mem: 1 GB.
system3
OS: 8.3-RELEASE FreeBSD 8.3-RELEASE #0: Mon Apr  9 21:23:18 UTC 2012     root@mason.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
DB: PostgreSQL 8.4.11 on amd64-portbld-freebsd8.3, compiled by GCC cc (GCC) 4.2.2 20070831 prerelease [FreeBSD], 64-bit

Tests system3:
query   parameter       time in ms
01      'de%'           7096
02      'de%'           7012
03      'den%'          6228
04      'den %'         6237
05      'den h%'        6145
06      'den ha%'       5640
07      'den haa%'      5512
08      'den haag%'     5561
```

The parameters mimic the way data is entered in the ajax application. These results are from  queries directly to the database through pgAdmin3, so not through the application. I haven't put the query here because I don't think that should be relevant. The databases are identical and the same query is used on all three database instances.

Now I can understand the performance difference between system1: OS X system, bare hardware and system2: virtual machine running FreeBSD.

What I don't understand is the huge performance difference between system2 and system3 which  are both vm's running under the same host. The test were done with each vm running individually.

Does anyone have a clue why this could be happening?

For all system I did a VACUUM ANALYZE first.

```
system1: PostgreSQL 8.4.5 on i386-apple-darwin10.5.0
"Limit  (cost=3894.65..3894.70 rows=20 width=36) (actual time=1445.667..1445.671 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=3894.65..3903.99 rows=3736 width=36) (actual time=1445.666..1445.666 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: public.geopoint_language.name_language, 



"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on geopoint  (cost=0.00..618.94 rows=625 width=11) (actual time=0.018..6.277 rows=728 loops=1)"
"                                                        Filter: (((admin2_code)::text = ''::text) AND (country_id = 154))"
"Total runtime: 1446.377 ms"


system2: PostgreSQL 8.4.7 on amd64-portbld-freebsd8.2
"Limit  (cost=3794.26..3794.31 rows=20 width=36) (actual time=64848.595..64848.903 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=3794.26..3800.41 rows=2460 width=36) (actual time=64848.583..64848.679 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: public.geopoint_language.name_language, adm2_state_language.name_language, adm1_state_language.name_language"
"        Sort Method:  top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB"
"        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=3704.20..3728.80 rows=2460 width=36) (actual time=64843.710..64846.020 rows=417 loops=1)"
"              ->  Append  (cost=1055.08..3667.30 rows=2460 width=36) (actual time=1201.210..64839.849 rows=417 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=1055.08..1784.76 rows=163 width=48) (actual time=1201.199..64707.965 rows=362 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: (adm1_state_language.language_id = public.language.id)"
"                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=1049.36..1776.47 rows=287 width=64) (actual time=1200.852..64703.138 rows=362 loops=1)"
"                                Merge Cond: (public.state.pstate_id = public.state.id)"
"                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=843.55..3856.49 rows=470 width=72) (actual time=1199.848..64693.793 rows=362 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=843.55..2641.98 rows=4159 width=58) (actual time=39.390..64356.535 rows=13768 loops=1)"
"                                            Join Filter: ((public.state.admin2_code)::text = (public.geopoint.admin2_code)::text)"
"                                            ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=217.62..758.39 rows=8 width=51) (actual time=38.388..146.171 rows=862 loops=1)"
"                                                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=217.62..754.28 rows=15 width=47) (actual time=38.361..124.606 rows=862 loops=1)"
"                                                        ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=217.62..616.50 rows=20 width=34) (actual time=38.332..87.939 rows=918 loops=1)"
"                                                              ->  Merge Join  (cost=217.62..606.79 rows=35 width=30) (actual time=38.300..58.248 rows=1066 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Merge Cond: (adm1_state_language.state_id = public.state.pstate_id)"
"                                                                    ->  Index Scan using idx_state_language_1 on state_language adm1_state_language  (cost=0.00..392.25 rows=7120 width=21) (actual time=0.019..16.666 rows=2826 loops=1)"
"                                                                          Index Cond: (preferred = true)"
"                                                                    ->  Sort  (cost=196.31..196.48 rows=68 width=9) (actual time=6.551..12.945 rows=1065 loops=1)"
"                                                                          Sort Key: public.state.pstate_id"
"                                                                          Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 45kB"
"                                                                          ->  Seq Scan on state  (cost=0.00..194.24 rows=68 width=9) (actual time=0.019..3.928 rows=431 loops=1)"
"                                                                                Filter: (((admin2_code)::text <> ''::text) AND (country_id = 154) AND ((admin3_code)::text = ''::text) AND ((admin4_code)::text = ''::text))"
"                                                              ->  Index Scan using pk_language_all on language  (cost=0.00..0.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=1066)"
"                                                                    Index Cond: (public.language.id = adm1_state_language.language_id)"
"                                                                    Filter: public.language.enabled"
"                                                        ->  Index Scan using idx_state_language_1 on state_language adm2_state_language  (cost=0.00..6.87 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.011..0.018 rows=1 loops=918)"
"                                                              Index Cond: ((adm2_state_language.state_id = public.state.id) AND (adm2_state_language.language_id = adm1_state_language.language_id) AND (adm2_state_language.preferred = true))"
"                                                  ->  Index Scan using pk_language_all on language  (cost=0.00..0.27 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=862)"
"                                                        Index Cond: (public.language.id = adm1_state_language.language_id)"
"                                                        Filter: public.language.enabled"
"                                            ->  Materialize  (cost=625.93..695.80 rows=6987 width=12) (actual time=0.005..36.752 rows=6884 loops=862)"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on geopoint  (cost=0.00..618.94 rows=6987 width=12) (actual time=0.015..45.945 rows=6884 loops=1)"
"                                                        Filter: (((admin2_code)::text <> ''::text) AND (country_id = 154))"
"                                      ->  Index Scan using idx_geopoint_language_3 on geopoint_language  (cost=0.00..0.28 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=0 loops=13768)"
"                                            Index Cond: ((public.geopoint_language.geopoint_id = public.geopoint.id) AND (public.geopoint_language.language_id = adm1_state_language.language_id))"
"                                            Filter: (public.geopoint_language.endonym AND ((public.geopoint_language.name_language)::text ~~* 'de%%'::text))"
"                                ->  Sort  (cost=205.72..206.42 rows=282 width=4) (actual time=0.984..3.008 rows=342 loops=1)"
"                                      Sort Key: public.state.id"
"                                      Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on state  (cost=0.00..194.24 rows=282 width=4) (actual time=0.427..0.850 rows=12 loops=1)"
"                                            Filter: ((country_id = 154) AND ((admin2_code)::text = ''::text) AND ((admin3_code)::text = ''::text) AND ((admin4_code)::text = ''::text))"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=5.51..5.51 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.235..0.235 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on language  (cost=0.00..5.51 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.127 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: enabled"
"                    ->  Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=1844.22..1880.91 rows=2297 width=35) (actual time=125.544..127.175 rows=55 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Merge Join  (cost=1844.22..1857.94 rows=2297 width=35) (actual time=125.533..126.563 rows=55 loops=1)"
"                                Merge Cond: ((adm1_state_language.language_id = public.geopoint_language.language_id) AND ((public.state.admin1_code)::text = (public.geopoint.admin1_code)::text))"
"                                ->  Sort  (cost=392.00..392.29 rows=117 width=26) (actual time=82.529..82.647 rows=24 loops=1)"
"                                      Sort Key: adm1_state_language.language_id, public.state.admin1_code"
"                                      Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 26kB"
"                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=209.42..387.98 rows=117 width=26) (actual time=30.234..82.289 rows=25 loops=1)"
"                                            Hash Cond: (adm1_state_language.language_id = public.language.id)"
"                                            ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=203.49..380.10 rows=206 width=22) (actual time=29.732..81.508 rows=25 loops=1)"
"                                                  Hash Cond: (adm1_state_language.language_id = public.language.id)"
"                                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=197.77..371.13 rows=364 width=18) (actual time=29.442..80.926 rows=29 loops=1)"
"                                                        Hash Cond: (adm1_state_language.state_id = public.state.id)"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on state_language adm1_state_language  (cost=0.00..143.03 rows=7120 width=21) (actual time=0.008..39.728 rows=7120 loops=1)"
"                                                              Filter: preferred"
"                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=194.24..194.24 rows=282 width=5) (actual time=2.366..2.366 rows=12 loops=1)"
"                                                              ->  Seq Scan on state  (cost=0.00..194.24 rows=282 width=5) (actual time=1.185..2.271 rows=12 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Filter: (((admin2_code)::text = ''::text) AND ((admin3_code)::text = ''::text) AND ((admin4_code)::text = ''::text) AND (country_id = 154))"
"                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=5.51..5.51 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.224..0.224 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on language  (cost=0.00..5.51 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.118 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                              Filter: enabled"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=5.72..5.72 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.445..0.445 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=5.55..5.72 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.233..0.323 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on language  (cost=0.00..5.51 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.125 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                              Filter: enabled"
"                                ->  Sort  (cost=1452.22..1453.21 rows=396 width=25) (actual time=42.856..43.140 rows=55 loops=1)"
"                                      Sort Key: public.geopoint_language.language_id, public.geopoint.admin1_code"
"                                      Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 29kB"
"                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=626.75..1435.14 rows=396 width=25) (actual time=23.266..42.430 rows=55 loops=1)"
"                                            Hash Cond: (public.geopoint_language.geopoint_id = public.geopoint.id)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on geopoint_language  (cost=0.00..802.94 rows=396 width=18) (actual time=3.081..25.949 rows=515 loops=1)"
"                                                  Filter: (endonym AND ((name_language)::text ~~* 'de %%'::text))"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=618.94..618.94 rows=625 width=11) (actual time=13.194..13.194 rows=728 loops=1)"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on geopoint  (cost=0.00..618.94 rows=625 width=11) (actual time=0.015..8.770 rows=728 loops=1)"
"                                                        Filter: (((admin2_code)::text = ''::text) AND (country_id = 154))"
"Total runtime: 64850.211 ms"


system3: PostgreSQL 8.4.11 on amd64-portbld-freebsd8.3
"Limit  (cost=2715.73..2715.78 rows=20 width=35) (actual time=28363.433..28363.721 rows=20 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=2715.73..2716.02 rows=113 width=35) (actual time=28363.421..28363.516 rows=20 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: public.geopoint_language.name_language, adm2_state_language.name_language, adm1_state_language.name_language"
"        Sort Method:  top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB"
"        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2711.60..2712.73 rows=113 width=35) (actual time=28358.553..28360.849 rows=419 loops=1)"
"              ->  Append  (cost=571.63..2709.90 rows=113 width=35) (actual time=349.502..28354.791 rows=419 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=571.63..884.24 rows=3 width=48) (actual time=349.492..28233.388 rows=362 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: (adm1_state_language.language_id = public.language.id)"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=565.91..878.47 rows=5 width=64) (actual time=349.172..28228.620 rows=362 loops=1)"
"                                Join Filter: ((public.state.admin2_code)::text = (public.geopoint.admin2_code)::text)"
"                                ->  Merge Join  (cost=565.91..811.16 rows=25 width=61) (actual time=278.147..20849.826 rows=292218 loops=1)"
"                                      Merge Cond: (public.state.pstate_id = adm1_state_language.state_id)"
"                                      Join Filter: (adm1_state_language.language_id = adm2_state_language.language_id)"
"                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=233.49..1199.63 rows=277 width=44) (actual time=12.014..10783.473 rows=292218 loops=1)"
"                                            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=233.49..725.31 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=7.617..42.736 rows=862 loops=1)"
"                                                  ->  Merge Join  (cost=233.49..720.62 rows=1 width=13) (actual time=7.585..16.639 rows=431 loops=1)"
"                                                        Merge Cond: (public.state.id = public.state.pstate_id)"
"                                                        ->  Index Scan using pk_state on state  (cost=0.00..523.51 rows=282 width=4) (actual time=1.000..2.268 rows=12 loops=1)"
"                                                              Filter: ((country_id = 154) AND ((admin2_code)::text = ''::text) AND ((admin3_code)::text = ''::text) AND ((admin4_code)::text = ''::text))"
"                                                        ->  Sort  (cost=196.31..196.48 rows=68 width=9) (actual time=6.566..9.020 rows=431 loops=1)"
"                                                              Sort Key: public.state.pstate_id"
"                                                              Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 45kB"
"                                                              ->  Seq Scan on state  (cost=0.00..194.24 rows=68 width=9) (actual time=0.015..3.942 rows=431 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Filter: (((admin2_code)::text <> ''::text) AND (country_id = 154) AND ((admin3_code)::text = ''::text) AND ((admin4_code)::text = ''::text))"
"                                                  ->  Index Scan using idx_state_language_1 on state_language adm2_state_language  (cost=0.00..4.68 rows=1 width=21) (actual time=0.012..0.026 rows=2 loops=431)"
"                                                        Index Cond: ((adm2_state_language.state_id = public.state.id) AND (adm2_state_language.preferred = true))"
"                                            ->  Index Scan using idx_geopoint_language_3 on geopoint_language  (cost=0.00..471.76 rows=205 width=18) (actual time=2.051..8.854 rows=339 loops=862)"
"                                                  Index Cond: (public.geopoint_language.language_id = adm2_state_language.language_id)"
"                                                  Filter: (public.geopoint_language.endonym AND ((public.geopoint_language.name_language)::text ~~* 'de%%'::text))"
"                                      ->  Sort  (cost=331.82..337.54 rows=2286 width=29) (actual time=237.631..3511.098 rows=625149 loops=1)"
"                                            Sort Key: adm1_state_language.state_id"
"                                            Sort Method:  quicksort  Memory: 746kB"
"                                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=11.87..204.28 rows=2286 width=29) (actual time=0.996..192.413 rows=7023 loops=1)"
"                                                  Hash Cond: (adm1_state_language.language_id = public.language.id)"
"                                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=5.94..180.49 rows=4035 width=25) (actual time=0.514..116.195 rows=7023 loops=1)"
"                                                        Hash Cond: (adm1_state_language.language_id = public.language.id)"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on state_language adm1_state_language  (cost=0.00..143.03 rows=7120 width=21) (actual time=0.007..38.638 rows=7120 loops=1)"
"                                                              Filter: preferred"
"                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=5.72..5.72 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.452..0.452 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=5.55..5.72 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.260..0.350 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on language  (cost=0.00..5.51 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.136 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                                          Filter: enabled"
"                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=5.72..5.72 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.425..0.425 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=5.55..5.72 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.231..0.322 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                              ->  Seq Scan on language  (cost=0.00..5.51 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.118 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Filter: enabled"
"                                ->  Index Scan using pk_city on geopoint  (cost=0.00..2.68 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.008..0.011 rows=1 loops=292218)"
"                                      Index Cond: (public.geopoint.id = public.geopoint_language.geopoint_id)"
"                                      Filter: (((public.geopoint.admin2_code)::text <> ''::text) AND (public.geopoint.country_id = 154))"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=5.51..5.51 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.230..0.230 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on language  (cost=0.00..5.51 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.124 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: enabled"
"                    ->  Subquery Scan "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=1014.04..1825.63 rows=110 width=35) (actual time=100.899..116.913 rows=57 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Hash Join  (cost=1014.04..1824.53 rows=110 width=35) (actual time=100.889..116.323 rows=57 loops=1)"
"                                Hash Cond: (((public.geopoint.admin1_code)::text = (public.state.admin1_code)::text) AND (public.geopoint_language.language_id = adm1_state_language.language_id))"
"                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=626.75..1432.19 rows=19 width=25) (actual time=19.280..34.017 rows=57 loops=1)"
"                                      Hash Cond: (public.geopoint_language.geopoint_id = public.geopoint.id)"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on geopoint_language  (cost=0.00..802.94 rows=616 width=18) (actual time=1.942..16.204 rows=720 loops=1)"
"                                            Filter: (endonym AND ((name_language)::text ~~* 'de%%'::text))"
"                                      ->  Hash  (cost=618.94..618.94 rows=625 width=11) (actual time=13.437..13.437 rows=728 loops=1)"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on geopoint  (cost=0.00..618.94 rows=625 width=11) (actual time=0.012..8.923 rows=728 loops=1)"
"                                                  Filter: (((admin2_code)::text = ''::text) AND (country_id = 154))"
"                                ->  Hash  (cost=385.53..385.53 rows=117 width=26) (actual time=81.568..81.568 rows=25 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=209.64..385.53 rows=117 width=26) (actual time=29.986..81.410 rows=25 loops=1)"
"                                            Hash Cond: (adm1_state_language.language_id = public.language.id)"
"                                            ->  Hash Join  (cost=203.70..378.69 rows=206 width=22) (actual time=29.457..80.612 rows=25 loops=1)"
"                                                  Hash Cond: (adm1_state_language.language_id = public.language.id)"
"                                                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=197.77..371.13 rows=364 width=18) (actual time=29.011..79.869 rows=29 loops=1)"
"                                                        Hash Cond: (adm1_state_language.state_id = public.state.id)"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on state_language adm1_state_language  (cost=0.00..143.03 rows=7120 width=21) (actual time=0.008..38.849 rows=7120 loops=1)"
"                                                              Filter: preferred"
"                                                        ->  Hash  (cost=194.24..194.24 rows=282 width=5) (actual time=2.245..2.245 rows=12 loops=1)"
"                                                              ->  Seq Scan on state  (cost=0.00..194.24 rows=282 width=5) (actual time=1.139..2.167 rows=12 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Filter: (((admin2_code)::text = ''::text) AND ((admin3_code)::text = ''::text) AND ((admin4_code)::text = ''::text) AND (country_id = 154))"
"                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=5.72..5.72 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.423..0.423 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=5.55..5.72 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.226..0.317 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                              ->  Seq Scan on language  (cost=0.00..5.51 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.008..0.119 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Filter: enabled"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=5.72..5.72 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.449..0.449 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=5.55..5.72 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.254..0.344 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on language  (cost=0.00..5.51 rows=17 width=4) (actual time=0.010..0.119 rows=17 loops=1)"
"                                                              Filter: enabled"
"Total runtime: 28366.784 ms"
```

The times shown for system2 and system3 don't make any sense to me.

Comment: Could be many things, but first check that cache and other low level disk configurations are identical. Big performance differences are almost always differences in disk IO.

Comment: Run the queries manually with EXPLAIN ANALYZE so you can see where the time goes and if the plans are the same. You might want to run VACUUM ANALYZE on both first to make sure the statistics are up to date. Add the output of explain analyze for both to your question. How large is the DB? If it is not much more then 1 GB disk IO is probably not the problem as everything will be in the OS cache after a couple of runs.

Comment: Please check the configation values for {shared_buffers, effective_cache_size, work_mem, random_page_cost} on both machines. (setting shared buffers *too high* can have negative effects on VMs, IIRC)

Comment: Most values are at their default values I only changed work_mem for the OS X system for test. System1, PostgreSQL 8.4.5 OS X shared_buffers = 2400kB, work_mem = 16 MB. System2, PostgreSQL 8.4.7 FreeBSD 8.2 shared_buffers = 28MB. System3, PostgreSQL 8.4.11 FreeBSD 8.3 shared_buffers = 28MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put your two explain plans under question in explain.depesz.com: [system2](http://explain.depesz.com/s/f7s), [system3](http://explain.depesz.com/s/3Si) to make it easier to understand and interpret them.

Now these plans are pretty large, so it's not too surprising that they differ when executed under two different versions of postgresql.  Even patch releases make changes that can effect the planner, bug fixes or minor optimizations in one place can change decisions in another.

Something that jumps out for me is that the system3 plan has noticeable discrepancies in the estimated vs actual row cardinality of many steps in the execution. For example line 7 and 8 had actual rows 292K, but estimated rows 25 and 277; line 16, 625K vs 2286.  In contrast, system2 had no plan lines with such gross mis-estimations, there are a few that missed by one order of magnitude on a fairly modest total count, but nothing missing by several orders of magnitude producing row cardinality in the 100K+ range.

Such differences may indicate that you have incorrect statistics on system3 which cause that pg instance to choose a less efficient plan because it has inaccurate data about the cost of its choices. You may want to try reanalyzing all your tables and possibly increasing the [statistics target](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-DEFAULT-STATISTICS-TARGET).

Have you verified that the data is identical on each system? Also check that all the [query planning settings](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-query.html) are the same on the two systems.

I also wonder why you are even bothering which such an old version of postgres. 8.4 is many years old and there have been numerous substantial improvements in features, performance, and concurrency between 8.4 and 9.2.  It seems silly to spend substantial effort tuning a nearly obsolete version of postgres instead of targeting the latest stable release unless you are bound to it for compelling other reasons.

Comment: I am/was sticking with this 'old' postgresql release for the following reason. I started developing my application a while ago just before postgresql 9.0 was released. So during my development I tried to upgrade the database and ran into similar problem I described here. Then I decided to postpone the upgrade until I finished my development. I finished my development last Friday so I thought now is the time to work on the database upgrade.

So perhaps you are right. I will try to install a new vm with FreeBSD 9.x and PostgreSQL 9.x.

Comment: I forgot to say: thanks a lot to all of you. My problem is not over yet but like I just said I will install new vm with FreeBSD 9.x and PostgreSQL 9.x. first.